# Need to capture process ID from used url

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

After working 2 days to find a solution I give up and ask your help. I need to have a vbs that launch a url, let's say www.msn.nl, and then keep that script open until the user closes the IE with that same url. I programmed a script that works with the proces-id and works fine for a executable like notepad.exe. But this script doesn't work for Internet Explorer. When the url is launched the proces-id changes. And there is my problem. Somehow I need to get that new proces-id.

This is the script what I made until now:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objStartup = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")
Set objConfig = objStartup.SpawnInstance_
Set objProcess = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
errReturn = objProcess.Create("c:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe  www.msn.com", null, objConfig, PID)
'errReturn = objProcess.Create("notepad.exe", null, objConfig, PID)

' Verify Process Availability

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

ProcessItem = "Select * from Win32_Process Where ProcessID = " & PID
WScript.Echo PID

Do
Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery (ProcessItem)

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

If Not colProcesses.Count = 0 Then
    WScript.Sleep 1500
    'WScript.Echo "running"
Else
    WScript.Echo "quit"
    WScript.Quit
End If
Loop
```

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. *Why* are you trying to capture this particular PID?

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely non-trivial task due to Internet Explorer's multi-process architecture. On modern operating systems, there are multiple IE processes (one or more frame/manager processes and one or more tab/content processes) and there's no simple way to understand which belongs to which. Things are even more complicated if a navigation crosses from one security zone (e.g. Intranet) to another (e.g. Internet) as the navigation starts in one process and ends in another.

Let's back up-- Why do you need to accomplish this task?